# How to solve problem with repositories and update information is outdated message 14.04

Tags: 14.04, update-manager, repository

I am still new to linux and currently using 14.04 and not sure what to do to solve this situation. The problem arose as I was just trying to install spotify following [this guide](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/01/how-to-install-spotify-in-ubuntu-12-04-12-10) and I found myself receiving the following messages after the `sudo apt-get update -qq` command

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/quantal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/quantal/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 194.169.254.10 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 194.169.254.10 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 194.169.254.10 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 194.169.254.10 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And surely enough these repeated even after typing the `sudo apt-get install spotify-client`. I had not encountered these so I followed some guidelines and tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` followed by `sudo apt-get update` but no success.

Here is a copy of my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

## Multiarch sources
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports quantal main universe

deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
# deb-src http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

At the same time I also have the `The update information is outdated` notification in the top right corner. I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## Multiarch sources
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports quantal main universe
```

Those lines are for an old version of Ubuntu, remove them and do `sudo apt-get update`.

For PPA 404 errors follow this:

- [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages)

Comment: Thank you, I did this and the result is I still got the message `W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apt-fast/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found` I guess I need to get new PPA's?

Comment: The ppa for apt-fast should be removed - apt-fast has not been ported to trusty on the launchpad website, although I have read that it is available at some other source.